# Using php, how would I replace [0-9],[0-9] with [0-9][0-9]?

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have a string "1,000,786". I want this to be converted to "1000786". I understand the first part of the preg_replace would be something like "[0-9],[0-9]" but I don't understand how to get the number values back in the 'replace with' part of preg_replace. Thanks.

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention it's not as simple as just removing the comma since alphabetic characters may be included. Only if the comma is between 2 numbers do I want it to go away.

Example: "Apple, Banana 1,746" would be "Apple, Banana 1746".

Comment: You don't need regular expressions at all to [remove a fixed character](http://php.net/str_replace) like `,`, unless it's an exercise.

Comment: You say _it is not that simple as just removing the comma_. Can you show an example where it is not just as simple as removing the comma? the example you gave just removing the comma isn't it?

Comment: If you look at the example the comma remains between Apple and Banana.

Comment: @user1413341 edited my answer to answer CORRECTLY  your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below regex would remove the comma's only if it's preceded by a number and it must be followed by a number.

```
(?<=\d),(?=\d)
```

Replacement string:

```
Empty string
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tJ0yG2/3)

Your code would be,

```
<?php
$string = '1,000,786';
$pattern = "~(?<=\d),(?=\d)~";
$replacement = "";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?> //=> 1000786
```

OR

```
<?php
$string = 'Apple, Banana 1,746';
$pattern = "~(?<=\d),(?=\d)~";
$replacement = "";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?> //=> Apple, Banana 1746
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to use regular expressions for that, a call to str_replace() is sufficient:

```
$s = str_replace(",", "", "1,000,786");
```

Answer (score 1):

For handling also the text before please consider the following code:

```
$text = 'Apple, Banana, 1,746';
preg_match('/[0-9]+,[0-9]+/', $text, $matches);
$text = str_replace($matches[0], str_replace(',', '', $matches[0]), $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for:

```
/(\d+),(\d+)(?:,(\d+))?/
```

And replace it to:

```
$1$2$3
```

<kbd>[Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tJ0yG2/4)</kbd>